# What does "trouble at pit" mean?

Tags: expressions, british-english, phrase-meaning

I saw this in an article about which British accents sound more intelligent, apparently Yorkshire was once deemed as a place with "trouble at pit".

It probably has an origin related to auto racing, but I would like to know the exact meaning and how to use the phrase.

Comment: It's probably something to do with coal mining, as Yorkshire is known for its collieries: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collieries_in_Yorkshire_(1984%E2%80%93present)

Comment: _When a' wert lad_ it was a common phrase to use to ask someone if something was wrong (not just in Yorkshire). I'm not sure but I think the phrase was 'overpopularised' by 60/70's UK TV serialised drama which I can't remember the name of where a young boy would run in to his house and proclaim _Mam, Da, come quick, there's trouble at pit._ The _pit_ does indeed mean a shaft coal mine and the _trouble_ was either an accident or a union/worker/boss based problem. It's use now is idiomatic to mean 'a problem'. If I can remember the TV show I'll add another comment.

Comment: I think _trouble at mill_ was an even earlier version of the same thing, this time relating to the cotton mills of 19th Century (Northern) England.

Comment: @frank - such as when the cross-beam goes out of skew on the treddle ?

Comment: @mgb Sort of ... but I didn't expect a Spanish Inquisition!

Comment: @Frank-thank you so much for your comment, that background info definitely cleared things up for me! So it's a bit like saying "trouble at the old mill", a reference to the show Lassie. Now the challenge for me as an American is whether it would make any sense to say this phrase! I like it so much, I'm gonna do it anyway.

Comment: There is no shortage of Americans on this site, so perhaps one or two might chime in with their feelings. It is along similar lines to the Lassie phrase. I'm not sure if it's still in use in the UK amongst the younger generation, but I'm confident _trouble at mill_ will still be widely known as it's the older of the two, _trouble at pit_ might have slipped a bit due to the demise of the coal mining industry. The only TV series I can think of is the 60's drama _Inheritance_ but that was about cotton mills.

Answer (score 2):

*Collected comments to avoid the possibility of deletion and if anyone can remember the TV show feel free to edit it in.*

*When a' wert lad* it was a common phrase to use to ask someone if something was wrong (not just in Yorkshire).

I'm not sure but I think the phrase was 'overpopularised' by a 60/70's UK TV serialised drama (which I can't remember the name of) where a young boy would run in to his house and proclaim *Mam, Da, come quick, there's trouble at pit*.

The *pit* does indeed mean a shaft coal mine and the *trouble* was either an accident or a union/worker/boss based problem. It's use now is idiomatic to mean 'a problem'.

*Trouble at mill* was an even earlier version of the same thing, this time relating to the cotton mills of 19th Century (Northern) England.

There is no shortage of Americans on this site, so perhaps one or two might chime in with their feelings. It is along similar lines to the Lassie phrase *Trouble at the old mill*. I'm not sure if it's still in use in the UK amongst the younger generation, but I'm confident *trouble at mill* will still be widely known as it's the older of the two, *trouble at pit* might have slipped a bit due to the demise of the coal mining industry.

The only TV series I can think of is the 60's drama *Inheritance* but that was about cotton mills. I keep thinking of Norman Wisdom but that would not have been a series.

**ETA :**

Further investigation shows that *Inheritance* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(TV_series) is the TV show that made *trouble at mill* a 'catchphrase' which could be what prompted Monty Python to parody it a few years later.

I'm now thinking that possibly *When the boat comes in* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_the_Boat_Comes_In popularised *trouble at pit*.

Comment: It's probably worth saying that "at mill" and "at pit" have a very strong glottal stop on "at" in order to include "the" and might even be written with an apostrophe to indicate the omission. (Compare *int' mill* -- the *t* is a glottal there too, not a /t/.)

Comment: Ah thought 'twere *Monty Python* tha' popularised this usage.

Comment: I have always understood the phrases to be spelled *trouble at t'pit /t'mill*, but that's quite hard to pronounce.